# Many File does not exist in Cpanel error log

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I have so many errors with file does not exist in CPanel error log. I've tried all the methods founded here but no luck. Below is a sample of my error log:

```
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:12 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.119] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:12 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.119] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.118] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.118] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.114] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.118] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.117] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.112] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.116] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.114] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.117] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.113] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.115] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.116] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.117] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.112] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.115] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.117] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 69.171.245.113] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 66.249.70.173] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/tags
[Tue Apr 29 09:28:11 2014] [error] [client 31.13.99.114] File does not exist: /home/.../public_html/politic
```

Please, give me a hand! The problem is that all file does not exist links are actually categories in site or articles in site.

Comment: Please give us to more information

Comment: Actually, all the article links, category links, tag links, font links are interpreted as file or folders in public_html, which is not correct. My question is how to make the client access www.domainname/category or www.domainname/category/article to get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if permissions are correctly set on folders, the folder should exist with same name (dont forget caps etc.) and cpanel require correct file and folder permissions, the file permissions bits should not be more than 644 and folder permission bits should not be more than 755.

Comment: The folders that apears in error log doesn't exists. In fact, those are categories in website. I don't know how to check or restore folders/files permisions.

Comment: yourwebsite.com/politic is taken as if there is a folder named politic in your document root, please make redirection rules via code or server settings so that yourwebsite.com/politic redirects to the desired link

Comment: The error is because of the redirection rule set on the server via .htaccess file mostly. These redirection rules state which part of website to redirect where. Please check if redirection is set properly in .htaccess file. 

For refrence the default .htaccess file for drupal is given here https://code.google.com/p/drupalgooglecode/source/browse/trunk/.htaccess

Comment: Thank for help! Could you take a look on my htacess file? It's made by our ex-programmer and is based on Joomla htaccess.